# "java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 26:" while trying to Get URL

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

From JMeter, I am trying to get a URL . (http://Uniform_resource_locator:port_0000/abc/def/ghi/content/login.html )

When I create an HTTP request and do a GET on that, I get the following error.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 26: http://[URL as mentioned above]/
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
```

- I have removed http:// from the server
- This is just a GET request.
- This is running on a VPN Network (JMeter is also on that machine)
- Opens manually.

Any ideas where I went wrong .

Comment: I tried this as well.. No Luck...

Comment: Add this to <jmeter_home>/bin/jmeter file.

Find Variable :

ARGS="$SERVER $DUMP $HEAP $NEW $SURVIVOR $TENURING $PERM $CLASS_UNLOAD"
And add :

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
You will get:

ARGS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true $SERVER $DUMP $HEAP $NEW $SURVIVOR $TENURING $PERM $CLASS_UNLOAD"

Comment: I tried google.com, it works...But not this link.....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Workaround i got here, was to Install Blazemeter chrome extension and record from Blazemeter and publish as a .jmx file.

Later , i opened a new test in Jmeter and imported this file.

I gave Authroization details. It worked. :)

Answer (score 1):

http://Uniform_resource_locator:port_0000/abc/def/ghi/content/login.html

in your link, use your link as shown below

```
Uniform_resource_locator:port_0000/abc/def/ghi/content/login.html
```

Then it works fine. because protocol `[http]:` is already there in `jmeter`